# asp-for does not work in my .NET 7 project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

`asp-for` and `asp-validation-for` do not work for sending data and validation (on a Razor page on Mac OS).

`credential.UserName` is empty and `credential.Password` why all time is empty.

sapn text-danger not worked .

My system is Mac OS and ASP.NET Core 7 with Visual Studio 2022

UI :

```
<div class="container border" style="padding:20px">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <!-- UserName part Form -->
        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="credential.UserName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" asp-for="credential.UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="credential.UserName" ></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Password part Form -->
        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="credential.Password"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="password" asp-for="credential.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="credential.Password"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Submit Part Form -->
        <div class="mb-3 row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
namespace WebAppSecurity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public Credential credential { get; set; } = new Credential();

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
                return Page();

            // Verify the credentials
            if(credential.UserName == "admin" && credential.Password == "admin")
            {
                // Creating the security context
                var Claims = new List<Claim> 
                                 {
                                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,"admin"),
                                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@gmail.com")
                                 };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, "MyCookieAuth");

                ClaimsPrincipal claimsprincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth", claimsprincipal);

                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }

    public class Credential
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Description = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [BindProperty] attribute: Can be applied to a public property of a
> controller or PageModel class to cause model binding to target that
> property:

Try to add `[BindProperty]`:

```
 [BindProperty]
 public Credential credential { get; set; } = new Credential();
```

result:

[image]

> Client-side validation prevents submission until the form is valid.
> The Submit button runs JavaScript that either submits the form or
> displays error messages.

try to add  script references after your form to support client-side validation:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

result:

[image]
You can read [[BindProperty] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindproperty-attribute) and [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation)
 to know more.